Parallel for-loop in bash with simultaneous sequential execution of another task with dependencies on the parallelized loop
In my bash script, I need to execute two different functions, taskA and taskB, which take an integer ($i) as an argument. Since taskB $i depends on the completion of taskA $i, the following abbreviated piece of code does the job:
#!/bin/bash

taskA(){
  ...
}

taskB(){
  ...
}

for i in {1..100};
do
  taskA $i
  taskB $i
done

As taskA can be run at different $i independently, I can create a semaphore (taken from here Parallelize a Bash FOR Loop) and execute it in parallel. However, taskB $i requires the completion of taskA $i and the previous taskB $(i-1). Therefore, I just run them sequentially afterwards:
#!/bin/bash

open_sem(){
  mkfifo pipe-$$
  exec 3<>pipe-$$
  rm pipe-$$
  local i=$1
  for((;i>0;i--)); do
    printf %s 000 >&3
  done
}

run_with_lock(){
  local x
  read -u 3 -n 3 x && ((0==x)) || exit $x
  (
   ( "$@"; )
  printf '%.3d' $? >&3
  )&
}

taskA(){
  ...
}

taskB(){
  ...
}

N=36
open_sem $N
for i in {1..100};
do
  run_with_lock taskA $i
done

wait

for i in {1..100};
do
  taskB $i
done

In order to further optimize the procedure, is it possible to keep the semaphore for the parallel execution of taskA and run taskB simultaneously in such a way that it does not "overtake" taskA and waits for the completion of the taskA it depends on?

this seems – involved. First reaction here would be: are you sure it's not time to switch to something less shell, more programming language?

( taskA $i; taskB $i ) & ?


However, taskB $i requires the completion of taskA $i and the previous taskB $(i-1).

AFACT, you do this by running a single taskA and a single taskB in parallel; namely: taskA $i and taskB $i-1
It can be done like this:
taskA() { echo dummy A=$1; }
taskB() { echo dummy B=$1; }
export -f taskA taskB

# Do the inital warm up so we can run taskA $i, taskB $i-1
taskA 1
taskA 2
taskB 1
# Now taskA $i and taskB $i-1 is done for $i=2

doit() {
    i=$1
    a=$i
    b=$((i - 1))
    # Run 'taskA $1' and 'taskB $i-1' in parallel
    parallel ::: "taskA $a" "taskB $b"
}
export -f doit

seq 3 1000 | parallel -j1 doit

GNU Parallel will be started once for every $i giving around 0.2 sec overhead. If your jobs are short (< 1 sec), this overhead might be too big.
